# Not able to create equal gap between two div's because of image element inside one of the div

Tags: html, position, positioning

Looking at this image might make things clear..

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/w9vad/)**

[image]

[image]

The main container is a div in which there are 5 more div's each of them holding some data.

If the count for that data is 0 then , just display the text . 
If the count is greater than 0 , then shown count and image nested inside a span and the image and number are clickable...

The second image is to show how the text inside the div is being rendered..

Because of the **image**  in the 3rd and the 5th div's the gap between the div's is not being consistent . Even after setting the image to `position:relative` and `position:absolute` , setting the left and top property seems to have no affect ..

Can someone help me out in this context ..

**HTML**

```
<div id="prop">
   <div id="lvl1" class="alrt">
      Missing reads within 1 week : <span data-tr="1">0</span>
   </div>
   <div id="lvl2" class="alrt">
      Latest reads 1 Week or older : <span data-tr="2">0</span>
   </div>
   <div id="lvl3" class="alrt">
      Occupied Zero Consumption : <span data-tr="3"><a>39 <img src="../icon1.png" title="" /></a></span>
   </div>
   <div id="lvl4" class="alrt">
      Negative Consumption : <span data-tr="4">0</span>
   </div>
   <div id="lvl5" class="alrt">
      Vacant Consumption: <span data-tr="5"><a>5 <img src="../icon2.png" title="" /></a></span>
   </div>
   <div class="msg">
      *all alerts are based on yesterdays reads
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#prop
{
    height:55%;
    padding-top:10px;
    border:solid 2px #B2CD48;
    border-radius:10px;
    margin:10px 0 10px 15px;
}

#prop > .alrt 
{
    width:80%;
    float:right;
    height:12%;
    font-weight:700;
    font-size:1em;
    color:#42456B;
    padding:3px;
}

.alrt a 
{
    cursor:pointer;
    position:relative;
}

.alrt > span > a > img 
{
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    position:relative;
    top:3px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this for .alrt > span > a > img

```
.alrt > span > a > img
{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -3px;
}
```

Comment: I tied absolute instead of relative and it seems to be working fine .. Also how can I align the image such that it comes right after the number .. If I give a fixed left: 20px .. Then it seems to align for single digit , but this does not help if the number is double or triple dight

Comment: True, If I specify the CSS leaving out the left , then they seem to be overlapping ..

Comment: It is not working for you?  What browser are you using so I can make sure I'm looking at the same thing.

Comment: I'm not really sure.  They don't overlap for me for whatever reason.